# Download only physics and maths wikipedia pages for offline use

Tags: soft-question

There are tools for downloading the entire wikipedia database (above 8 Gb without pictures), but I would like to download only physics and maths pages, to view them offline. Wikipedia pages have a tree structure in categories, so it should be possible.

Please see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download):

> To download a subset of the database in XML format, such as a specific category or a list of articles se[...]

and a link to some other page from which, after many efforts, I could surely get what I want. I am just wondering if anyone has already done it and can save me/us the effort with a few "how to" guidelines.

I know wikipedia seems for many of you not much an orthodox source, but it is usually an excellent introduction to areas that are not in your main line of research/study. I miss it very often while commuting.

Comment: You want to download _all_ the wiki pages?! It seems improbable that you'd ever need a reference of all the wikipedia pages on physics and math. Much better would be to look at the articles that interest you and then download them. But that's just my opinionated suggestion. :)

Comment: @Kitchi: Doesn't your suggestion imply you know upfront what you're going to look up?

Comment: @NickKidman - The way I usually look up Wiki is I look up something I don't know but know the name of, or something like that. But from that article there are plenty of other articles to jump to. So what I meant was it'll probably be more productive to just download those ones which seem something he may be interested in, rather than _everything_. But as I also mentioned, that's just how I'd do it.

Comment: @Kitchi: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Don%27t_abbreviate_as_Wiki.png](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Don%27t_abbreviate_as_Wiki.png)

Comment: @NickKidman - Hahaha! I can't edit comments, but duly noted sir!

Comment: It is not clear to me that this is on-topic. If you *have* a list of the pages it probably belongs on Super User (if you are looking for an existing app) or Stack Overflow (if you want to code it yourself). There doesn't seem to be a site to ask about identifying such pages (not webapps, nor webmasters): I'd start by looking at the code of some sample pages to see if wikipedia attaches some indexing data that you could take advantage of.

Comment: I know this isn't answering the question, **BUT** have you considered setting up a local wiki on your computer using MediaWiki and SQLite? That way, you can write up your own notes (a much more worth-while endeavour!) with your own references (e.g., which book on your shelf is helpful for this subject)...

Comment: I have rewritten the question. Please consider that it is essentially a bibliography question, before closing it (actually, it deals on how to get a huge general math and physics book in your portable device). Thanks.

Comment: @dmckee: Looks to me like this would be [on topic for webapps.SE](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq).  Certainly there are some similar questions already there, like [this one](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/26838/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-pages-belonging-to-a-wikipedia-portal).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I can ask the mods, but I don't think of wikipedia as a "web site that behaves like an application". Anyway, I'll get back to that after I hear from the mods over there.

Comment: @dmckee I agree, this absolutely seems off topic here. Wikipedia might count as a trivial web application though.

Comment: I would support Eduardo's claim that this is a bibliography question.

Comment: @dmckee, David Zaslavsky: Looks like the folks at meta.webapps [do think it's on topic](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/923/would-mediawiki-sites-like-wiktionary-be-considered-web-apps-for-the-purposes-of).

Comment: Feedback from one WebApps mod: *"I don't see how it can fit into webapps, agree with your comment that Super User's more suitable"*. Not sure how that gets on with the meta.webapps link that @IlmariKaronen found. I'm waiting for the time being.

Comment: I'll close it in the meantime.

Comment: Let me suggest that perhaps you might be wasting too much energy trying to dilucidate if this is or is not on-topic... Closing questions protects this site from UFO issues, but taking it too seriously can be bad for your health. Take it easy, pals. I can't imagine Richard Feynman mixed in this discussion, but rather laughing at it. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a list of all physics and math articles on Wikipedia, you could run [CatScan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aCatScan) on [Category:WikiProject Physics articles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aWikiProject_Physics_articles) and [Category:WikiProject Mathematics articles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aWikiProject_Mathematics_articles), [like this](http://toolserver.org/~magnus/catscan_rewrite.php?depth=10&categories=WikiProject+Physics+articles%0D%0AWikiProject+Mathematics+articles&comb%5Bunion%5D=1&ns%5B0%5D=1&ns%5B1%5D=1&sortby=title).

Note that a lot of the pages returned by CatScan will be article talk pages, since that's where the WikiProject templates normally go.  Depending on the output format you choose, you may need to postprocess the list to remove the `Talk:` prefix from page titles.

You can then use [Special:Export](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help%3aExport) to download the actual articles.

Comment: As a matter of interest, how heavy is the whole thing? (i.e. all the maths+physics pages)

Comment: Hard to say.  The total article count I get from my query is a bit under 26,000.  Assuming an average of 4 kB per article (which is close to [the average for the whole Wikipedia](http://stats.wikimedia.org/EN/TablesArticlesBytesPerArticle.htm), although I suspect that physics and math articles may be longer than average due to having fewer very short stubs), that would imply a BOTE estimated total size of around 100 MB.  Note that that figure doesn't include any images; including them would most likely increase it by at least an order of magnitude.