# Correct expression for D'Alembert operator in $c=1$ units

Tags: special-relativity, units

In QFT texts with $c=1$ units (most of them), D'Alembert operator is written as:

$$\Box ={\partial^2 \over \partial t^2} - \nabla^2$$

For pedagogical purposes, however, some texts don't set $c=1$, and then

$$\Box =\frac{1}{c^2} {\partial^2 \over \partial t^2} - \nabla^2$$

Is that right? I am a bit confused because Wikipedia uses the second form [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert_operator) despite the fact that, in the very next line it is stated

> We have assumed units such that the speed of light $c=1$

Am I missing something very basic, or is that page in Wikipedia simply wrong?

---

EDIT: In other words, when $c=1$ is assumed, $c$ NEVER appears in the equations. Is that correct in QFT, just as it happens in GR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One should always keep in mind that the marvelous Wikipedia is constantly being updated by different users. Most of the time an update constitute an overall improvement, but there is always a danger that previous coherence gets lost when a new user change something in one place but not in the rest of the text.

So concretely, the sentence *We have assumed units such that the speed of light $c=1$* should of course have been removed after $c$ was restored in $\Box$. Also note that in the current version, Wikipedia mixes notations $g_{\mu\nu}$ and $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ for the flat metric.

Such minor flaws should always be expected of Wikipedia until a page has matured.

Comment: Yes, Wikipedia is marvelous and I use it a lot (see [my first closed question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/44020/download-only-physics-and-maths-wikipedia-pages-for-offline-use) for instance) I had noticed the "wrong" notation for the metric, but it is not critic, as long as you understand that you are in Minkowski space.

Answer (score 1):

```
Wikipedia is simply wrong!  They must have made a simple typo.
```

Comment: That is, $c$ NEVER appears in the equations when using $c=1$ units. Is that right? (Please confirm that only if you are sure and you are used to work with different books of QFT).

Comment: Yes, this is correct. At least in all QFT books I partially read, and these are a lot.

Comment: Of course it doesn't appear. It's *actually* ONE if you choose these units.

Comment: @twistor59, thanks for your quick answer. I have upvoted it. I had to give the "answered" mark to someone, and I choosed the other question because it had additional information (the other, not critical, typo with the notation for the metric) but thanks very much.

Comment: @EduardoGuerrasValera no problem.  I think you can upvote Qmechanic's answer in addition to accepting it.

Comment: @Bzazz, I think the question is more subtle than merely 'of course c doesn't appear because c=1'. That choice of units goes beyond a numerical value, since what you do is using a unit of length for the time coordinate $x^0$. It is so in GR and then a velocity should never appear in that operator definition. I was wondering if perhaps the conventions in QFT were different in some texts (c=1 but still units of time for $t$ or anything more exotic? Who knows...)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the point. Of course you are choosing different units, but if $c=1$, it's 1, independently on other conventions. You can still use units of time for $t$, but then you should use them for space too...

Comment: @Bzazz, no, when you use units of time for $x^0$, the other coordinates still use space units, and then $c$ shall appear within the definition of interval, $ds^2=-c^2 dt^2+dx^2+dy^2+dz^2$ as well as in other relations, for consistency, regardless of its numerical value. You may work in yards per hour or whatever units you invent that make $c=1$ but still that $c$ shall appear in the formulas. It is the definition of $x^0$ as the *length* $ct$ what wipes away $c$ from the definitions, and not its numerical value of 1.

Comment: Ok, you mean for example if you use years for space and light years for time, you have different units but c=1.
But still, as long as you keep that unit system, there's no harm in getting rid of the c's.
Don't say it's needed for consistency of dimensions, because this holds also when you use natural units.

Answer (score 1):

$c$ is never *required* to appear in the questions when using a system of units where $c = 1$. Strictly speaking, it *can* appear as a multiplicative factor, just as you could write in a multiplicative factor of 1, but that would be very unusual, and also confusing because the presence of $c$ in an equation is conventionally taken as a sign that the equation is valid for systems of units where $c$ is not necessarily equal to 1.

As other answers said, this is one of the pitfalls of Wikipedia while an article is developing, which is why you have to use a bit of sense when evaluating the statements there.